# Automatically add hyperlinks to text in received emails

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

In Lotus Notes 8.5, is there a way I can automatically search received emails for a certain string and add a hyperlink/hotspot to every occurence of this string?

For example, can I make it so every email I receive containing the string 'Stack overflow' hyperlinks that text to stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a feature in the Notes client called "Live Text" that allows you to set up text patterns and actions and wire them together to do what you want.  Here is a link to an [article](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/09032009125637AMWEB7TF.htm) that describes the feature.